How to speed up GROUP BY on an indexed column?
I've got a query with a GROUP BY clause that is executed in 3-4s. The execution time drop to 0.05s if I remove GROUP BY.
GROUP BY already use an indexed value (-> the primary key of one of the tables).
Of course, I need the GROUP BY clause, I can't get rid of it.
What can I do to speed up this query ?
(It's one of the most frequently used queries of my application.)
Here is the query :
SELECT col1, col2, (...)
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2
   ON t2.fk_id = t1.a_id
JOIN table3 AS t3
   ON t3.fk_id = t2.id
JOIN table4 AS t4
   ON t4.fk_id = t1.b_id
JOIN table5 AS t5
   ON t5.fk_id = t4.id
LEFT JOIN table6 AS t6
   ON t6.fk_id = t1.c_id
LEFT JOIN table7 AS t7
   ON t7.fk_id = t6.id
WHERE t3.user_id = 12345
  AND t5.slug NOT IN ( 'slug_a','slug_b')
GROUP BY t1.id

EDIT :
Here is the result of the EXPLAIN command :
(The tables names are obviously not the same as in the query I wrote before...)



id
select_type
table
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
Extra infos




1
SIMPLE
p (=t3)
ref
PRIMARY,partners_index_32
partners_index_32
4
const
1
Using temporary; Using filesort


1
SIMPLE
o (=t2)
ref
PRIMARY,orders_index_1,id_client_id
orders_index_1
4
apicg.p.id
228



1
SIMPLE
i (=t1)
ref
items_index_7,item_gid
items_index_7
4
apicg.o.id
1
Using where


1
SIMPLE
v (=t4)
ref
product_variants_index_17, product_variants_index_18, global_id_product_id
product_variants_index_17
9
apicg.i.item_gid
1



1
SIMPLE
pr (=t5)
eq_ref
PRIMARY,products_index_16,id_name
PRIMARY
4
apicg.v.product_id
1
Using where


1
SIMPLE
d (=t6)
ref
to_provide,object_gid_to_validate
object_gid_to_validate
8
apicg.i.global_id
6
Using where


1
SIMPLE
inv (=t7)
ref
unique_2,invalidities_ibfk_3_idx
invalidities_ibfk_3_idx
5
apicg.d.id
99503
Using where




there is no way to incresase the speed, as mysql has to join 7 tables and create a lot of temp tables on the harddrove. Maybe you must restructure your database

@nbk Are you sure the JOINs are an issue ? Even with 7 tables this query is quick if I remove the GROUP BY.

@Charles.C get explain plan?

The problem is that it has to save the entire cross product in memory before doing the grouping. Without grouping, it can return rows incrementally.

Try move condition from WHERE to JOIN table3 AS t3  ON t3.fk_id = t2.id and t3.user_id = 12345 and JOIN table5 AS t5 ON t5.fk_id = t4.id AND t5.slug NOT IN ( 'slug_a','slug_b'). If query  don't use index on table1 (id), it is necessary sort by table1.id output before grouping. I think, this sort operation is expensive.

@Barmar So, if I understand correctly, JOINs are always detrimental to GROUP BY ?

I'm not going to say always, but they often are.

@ValNik The query is not quicker after these modifications.

@ValNik I'm pretty sure MySQL doesn't distinguish where you put the condition, except in the case of outer joins, since that has semantic implications.

Do you have index on table1(id)? Is this index used in query?

@Barmar, I won't argue with that. However, I have seen a difference in execution plans when placing conditions in ON and WHERE. The formulation of the conditions allows you to change the choice of the index by which the query will be built.

@ValNik t1.id has got an index (PRIMARY), but it seems it is not used here.

Then probably Using temporary; Using filesort - won't be able to get around it. There is too little information about the structure of the tables to help you.

please show the explain both with and without group by.  confirm that the 0.05s is real, not because you are using some UI client that is silently adding a limit clause; ideally use the command line client.

How id you measure/see the execution time (of 0.5 sec). Have you retrieved all 100k rows within that time?

When asking performance questions always include table definitions run show create table tableName for all related tables. By adding this information we can see the indexes ,collations storage engine of the tables. As per JOINs are always detrimental to GROUP BY I do not agree with that statement.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/internal-temporary-tables.html says:

The server creates temporary tables under conditions such as these:
...
Evaluation of statements that contain an ORDER BY clause and a different GROUP BY clause, or for which the ORDER BY or GROUP BY contains columns from tables other than the first table in the join queue.

(emphasis mine)
What this means with respect to your query:
The EXPLAIN shows that table t3 is the first in the join queue. But you GROUP BY t1.id, which the optimizer has put third in the join queue.
The optimizer can choose to reorder tables so they are accessed in a different order than you specified in your query. Usually the optimizer does this for good reasons, to give the bette performance advantage.
But you'll always see Using temporary table in the EXPLAIN if you GROUP BY a column from a table that is not ordered first by the optimizer.
You could try to force the table order, overriding the optimizer's choice. But this may result in worse performance for some other reason.
You could try to avoid temp tables on disk. Like making sure there are no TEXT or BLOB or JSON columns in your result if you don't need them. Or simply omitting other columns you don't need.
You could try changing the on-disk temp table storage engine.
You could get faster storage devices.
You could reduce your data so the temp table is smaller.
You could run the query less frequently, and rely on a cached result most of the time.
